# React js quill image upload

Tags: reactjs, image, file-upload, fetch, quill

I am trying to upload my image to the server by manually changing the Quill image upload function. Here is the error i get (by the way, there is no error related to API!), however I am stuck on it for couple of hours.

```
User trying to upload this: File {name: "rolling_pin.png", lastModified: 1588035813056, lastModifiedDate: Tue Apr 28 2020 04:03:33 GMT+0300, webkitRelativePath: "", size: 1289850, …}
quill.js:214 POST https://smartquestionapi.advancity.net/image 400
(anonymous) @ quill.js:214
quill.js:228 {error: true, response: 400, "rsponse: ": ""}
undefined:1 GET https://smartquestionapi.advancity.net/Images/undefined 404
```

Here is my code:

```
function imageHandler() {
    /*
    DEFAULT UPLOAD BY LINK

    var range = this.quill.getSelection();
    var value = prompt('What is the image URL');
    if (value) {
        this.quill.insertEmbed(range.index, 'image', value, Quill.sources.USER);
    }*/

    const input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
    input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');
    input.click();
    input.onchange = async function () {
        const file = input.files[0];
        console.log('User trying to upload this:', file);

        const formData = new FormData()
        if (file !== null) {
            formData.append('file', file)
        }
        fetch('https://smartquestionapi.advancity.net/image', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            },
            body: formData
        }).then(function (response) {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response.json()
            } else {
                return { "error": true,'response':response.status, 'rsponse: ':response.statusText }
            }
        }).then((json) => {
            console.log(json)
            var cursorPosition = this.quill.getSelection();
            var imagePath = "https://smartquestionapi.advancity.net/Images/" + json.imageUrl;
            this.quill.insertEmbed(cursorPosition.index, 'image', imagePath, Quill.sources.USER);
            return json;
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log("eror: ", err);
        })
    }.bind(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the file to files instead

```
if (file !== null) {
           formData.append('files', file)
    }
```